# check if success is done executing in http.get angular

Tags: angularjs

```
$scope.func1 = function() {
    $http.get(url, {params}).success(function(result){
        // code
    }).error(function(error){
        // error
    })
}

$scope.func2 = function() {
    $scope.func1();
    // when http of func1 done executing, call following code
}
```

How do I check in func2 if `http.get` success  of func1 is done executing?

Comment: Using [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Comment: possible using callback alone?

Comment: well, you probably should return something from `func1`, and consider using `.then` instead of the deprecated `.success`.  beyond that, a bit more code would be handy, to see what it is you are *actually* trying to do.

Comment: Okay, Thank you for that. but return what ?anything ?

Comment: as the answer provided shows, return the `$http` promise object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using promises properly you can chain multiple promises:

```
$scope.func1 = function () {
    return $http.get(url, {/*params*/})
        .then(function (response) { // success is deprecated, use then instead
            // code
            return something;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {   // use catch instead of error
            // error
        });
};


$scope.func2 = function () {
    $scope.func1().then(function(something) {
        //when http of func1 done executing, call following code
    });
};
```